# How to modify the name of a class when serializing it to JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an entity class as shown below.  I am using Json.Net to serialize it to JSON.  Now there are couple of fields / properties in the class which need to be serialized with different names from the actual properties, and that is easily achievable using the `[JsonProperty]` attribute as shown in the code below.  But what if I need to change the name of the main entity itself, which is marked with the `[JsonObject]` attribute?  (Here I am talking about the `UserDashboards` class which is derived from `EntityBase<int>`.) I have tried adding a few named parameters like title, id, etc. but they did not help.

```
     [JsonObject]
     public class UserDashboards : EntityBase<int>
     {  
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int DashboardID { get; set; }
        public int DashboardSequence { get; set; }
        public string DashboardTitle { get; set; }
        public int PermissionLevelID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("IsHome")]
        public Nullable<bool> IsHomeDashboard { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("IsShared")]
        public Nullable<bool> IsSharedDashboard { get; set; }             
      }
```

Comment: I thought question made it clear, anyway let me reiterate. The Json serialized name for the above mentioned class / entity UserDashboards has to be something like UserData. What more is required to explain this question ? What code snippets do you want and how would they help. I am asking whether same can be achieved in the attribute [JsonObject]. If we cannot achieve out here what special will the code do.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Json doesn't have a *name* for the *root* object as in xml. So there will not be a string like *UserDashboards* in your json string.

Comment: Your comment simply clarifies my doubt, I was just looking for the confirmation, as I could not find information on search, how to use JsonObject attribute to achieve the same. XML hangover was making me think it must be surely possible. Please do not down vote the question for any gap in understanding the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your object is at the root level in the JSON, it cannot be assigned a name.  Objects in JSON actually do not have names, per the specification (see [JSON.org](http://json.org)).  Object *properties* have names.  So if you effectively want to name your object in the JSON, you will need to wrap it in another object.  Then you can assign a name to that property in the wrapper object.  Like so:

```
class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("UserData")]
    public UserDashboards UserDashboards { get; set; }
}
```

If you then serialize the wrapper object then you will end up with JSON like this:

```
{
    "UserData" :
    {
        "UserID" : 42,
        "DashboardID" : 26,
        "DashboardSequence" : 1,
        "DashboardTitle" : "Foo",
        "PermissionLevelID" : 99,
        "IsHome" : true,
        "IsShared" : false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's how I exactly achieved it by wrapper it in another class and using that class object (Wrapper) for Json serialization